# How do developers who customise AOSP keep their changes under version control?

Tags: android, git, android-source

Fetching the AOSP source, is 134GB.

A checkout of a particular version of Android is likely to be many GBs.

How do developers who customise AOSP keep their changes under (their own) version control?  (Given that checking-in a snapshot of an Android version's source will be many GBs.)

Comment: Are you talking about OEMs, or individuals making custom ROMs in their spare time? For the former group, buying enough storage space is probably not that much of a problem.

Comment: The former, but time is as much of an issue as space.  (Untarring a big tgz is much faster than checking out.)

Comment: Well, when I was at Sony we'd typically get the sources from the Code Aurora Forum (for Qualcomm-based devices), and these would be the basis for our local git repos. I don't know the exact way in which the sources were downloaded, but they had people who had it as part of their job to manage this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my flow, maybe not the best....

I don't like dealing with repo tool and multiple remotes, so I get rid of all the .git subfolders and create just one tremendously huge repository.  This has the bad effect of essentially removing all the "history". So we have a server with the original sync for git blame if we need to.

First check-out for a developer will be time-consuming either way. To make it faster, we have a local **bare git repo** cloned. So people run git clone on the local server, and the switch the origin to the actual remote.

After all is set-up, the day-to-day dealings are not time consuming. Commits and pushes are quite fast ( maybe 5-10s ) even for a large repo like this. Thanks GIT!

Comment: Thanks for describing your workflow - I had expected the huge repo to be far more unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necro-posting, but maybe somebody find it useful.
I just use `repo` utility from Google, e.g. `repo start`.
Only first `repo sync` procedure take a long time,
even subsequent checkouts do not like so time-consuming.
If you check some popular ROM, e.g. GrapheneOS, you find they `repo` too.